# Error message when trying to convert folder with .txt files into one single .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, txt

everyone

I am desperately trying to convert 29.677 .txt files into one single .csv file with one column for the file names and one column for the text in the files. But when running the code on a sample size of 10 .txt files, I get the following error message:

> Error in data.frame(filename = basename(myfiles), fulltext = mytxts1lines) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 10, 150194

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm going insane...

I tried to run the following function to make it happen:
`

```
txt2csv <- function(my_dir, mycsvfilename) {
  starting_dir <- getwd()
  myfiles <- list.files(mydir, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.txt")
  mytxts <- lapply(myfiles, readLines)
  mytxts1lines <- unlist(mytxts)
  mytxtsdf <- data.frame(filename = basename(myfiles),
                         fulltext = mytxts1lines)
  setwd(mydir)
  write.table(mytxtsdf, file = paste0(mycsvfilename, ".csv"), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
  message(paste0("newspapers_csv_file", paste0(newspapers_csv_file, ".csv"), "C:\\Users\\[...]", getwd()))
  setwd(starting_dir)
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

When you say `filename = basename(myfiles)`, you are asking R to create a column called `filename`, of length `length(myfiles)`, which is 10. Then when you create the next column of 150194 rows, R cannot reconcile the two.

What you want to do is to create a `filename` vector of the same length as `mytxts` and make that the column name. We can do that with the `rep()` function, using the `lengths()` function to define how many times to repeat each filename.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
mytxts  <- list(
    letters[1:5],
    letters[1:10],
    letters[1:3]
)
myfiles  <- c("file1", "file2", "file3")
mytxts1lines <- unlist(mytxts)

myfiles1lines  <- rep(myfiles,lengths(mytxts))

data.frame(
    filename = myfiles1lines,
    fulltext = mytxts1lines
)

#    filename fulltext
# 1     file1        a
# 2     file1        b
# 3     file1        c
# 4     file1        d
# 5     file1        e
# 6     file2        a
# 7     file2        b
# 8     file2        c
# 9     file2        d
# 10    file2        e
# 11    file2        f
# 12    file2        g
# 13    file2        h
# 14    file2        i
# 15    file2        j
# 16    file3        a
# 17    file3        b
# 18    file3        c
```

In your case, you will want the argument to `rep()` to be `basename(myfiles)`.

```r
txt2csv <- function(my_dir, mycsvfilename) {
  starting_dir <- getwd()
  myfiles <- list.files(mydir, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "*.txt")
  mytxts <- lapply(myfiles, readLines)
  mytxts1lines <- unlist(mytxts)
  myfiles1lines  <- rep(basename(myfiles),lengths(mytxts)) # this line is new
  mytxtsdf <- data.frame(filename = myfiles1lines, # this line is changed
                         fulltext = mytxts1lines)
  setwd(mydir)
  write.table(mytxtsdf, file = paste0(mycsvfilename, ".csv"), sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
  message(paste0("newspapers_csv_file", paste0(newspapers_csv_file, ".csv"), "C:\\Users\\[...]", getwd()))
  setwd(starting_dir)
}
```